# Pasting contents of a page in Word to an Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to extract the text of an Word page from within an excel document using VBA.

So far I can manage to select the collection of pages using the .ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages selector, but I don't know how to get the text from a given page when I iterate over them. The looping is simple enough, but how can I get the text?

For example, if I just wanted to put the text from the 1st page into cell A1:

```
Dim objWord As New Word.Application
Dim objDoc As New Word.Document
Set objDoc = objWord.documents.Open("C:\wordfile.docx")

For Each currPage In objWord.ActiveWindows.Panes(1).Pages
    Range("A1") = ????
    Exit For
Next currPage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Pages` object in Word is confusing, to say the least. It's sort of an "after-thought" and really only reflects the layout, but doesn't give any access to the *content*. Word doesn't really have a "Page" object, anymore than it has a "Line" object. The reason for this is that Word is continually recalculating line and page breaks, so they're not "hard-and-fast" and therefore not reliable from one second to the next.

The way to access pages in Word is to loop through them, based more or less on the current selection, as demonstrated by the following procedure.

(This is Word VBA. I've put what you need in as comments, but of course the Excel Range and the objWord objects are not declared or instantiated. This makes it easier to follow what's needed in Word.)

```
Sub GetPageContent()
    Dim nrPages As Long
    Dim pg As Long
    Dim doc As word.Document
    Dim rngStart As word.Range
    Dim rngEnd As word.Range
    Dim rngPageContent As word.Range

    'objWord.documents.Open("C:\wordfile.docx")
    Set doc = Documents.Open("C:\wordfile.docx")
    nrPages = doc.content.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
    Set rngStart = doc.Range(0, 0)
    For pg = 2 To nrPages
        Set rngEnd = doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext, Name:=CStr(pg))
        Set rngPageContent = doc.Range(rngStart.Start, rngEnd.End)
        'Range("R1C" & Cstr(pg-1)) = pg - 1 & vbCr & rngPageContent
        Debug.Print pg - 1 & vbCr & rngPageContent
        Set rngStart = rngEnd.Duplicate
    Next
    'The last page
    Set rngPageContent = doc.Range(rngStart.Start, doc.content.End)
    'Range("R1C" & Cstr(pg-1)) = pg - 1 & vbCr & rngPageContent
    Debug.Print pg - 1 & vbCr & rngPageContent
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!